# How to detect when the user deletes the selected option from a dropdown menu Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu that I populate with ages.

When a user clicks on the dropdowm menu and selects and an option from the list, the right age is selected and stored in "ageSelected".

My problem comes when the user deletes the selected age and then leaves the age in blank, and the dropdown menu goes back to its original not filled status. I don't know how to capture this event, so that the old age is deleted and replaces by -1, meaning that no age has been selected. At the moment old age keeps being stored!

Thanks so much!

```
val ageArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.drop_down_item_age, ageValues)
            ageSpinner = binding.ageAutoCompleteTextView
            ageSpinner.setAdapter(ageArrayAdapter)
    
    
            ageSpinner.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
                // You can get the label or item that the user clicked:
                ageSelected = ageArrayAdapter.getItem(position)!!
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do it, create data class which has two proprties:

1. age: Int
2. checked: Boolean

in the initial state, create list of this class, set all age properties to the age values you want, and set all checked values to false.

now when the user chooses an age option, check the checked property of the chosen item in the array:

- if it is false, then the user is checking the age choice, you can safely take the age value, and change checked value to true.
- if it is true, then the user is unchecking the age choice, remove the age value to null or -1 or what ever you want, and set the checked property to false.

note: i do not know if there is a component or ready function to do it, but if i were you i would solve the problem logically.